# Consolidate according to the date in the last line of the excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple macro created to consolidate the files one below the other (i.e., find the last line and paste the next data)

So On a daily basis according to the date I need to consolidate the data (for a month - 30days)

My file is saved in the Path- I:\Tracker\2017\May'17

File Name : Signoff Sheet_May_**01** (This date May 01 everyday according to the calendar date)

The File Path and the date I have a sheet created named KPI and entered the details in there,

My code as follows :

```
Sub KPI()

    Set thiwkb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KPI")

    Mydate = thiwkb.Range("B2")

    Set destsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Production")

    Path = thiwkb.Range("B3") & "\" & "Signoff Sheet_" & Mydate & ".xlsx"

    Irow = 1
    Irow1 = 1
    Irow2 = 1

    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Path)
    wkb.Worksheets("Daily tracker").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination.Range("A" & Irow)

    wkb.Close False

    Irow = destsheet.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

End Sub
```

My Code is pulling the data however when I change the data in the KPI sheet everyday i need the data to be consolidated or pasted according to the date.

Comment: Try this : Destination:=thiwkb.Range("A" & Irow)

Comment: Or whichever book you're copying from and  too, The format for that is destination:=wb.ws.range("A1").  Did you leave out the code where you define the range by date?  I don't see it.

Comment: The code that u have mentioned is throwing me an debug error.

Comment: I have the dates mentioned on the worksheet called "KPI" - i will be changing the date on daily basis, All i need is as an when i change that date the destination sheet must pick the last line of the row and paste the data irrespective of the dates that i am choosing

Comment: Ok, I'm lost.  Your code is confusing me.  Lets start with pseudo code.  You need to "consolidate data for a month."  What does that mean?  Do you want to add a line to a worksheet for every day of a month?  Or are you taking all figures from a month and adding them all together on a single line of a workbook?  Next, this workbook you are writing to, are you creating a new workbook for each day of the month?  Or would you prefer to have one workbook for each month and add the daily totals on a new row within that workbook?  Name book you write to and the book you are drawing from.

Comment: 1) taking all figures from a month and adding them all together on a single worksheet of a workbook.
2)ave one workbook for each month and add the daily totals on a new row within that workbook . Name book you write to = KPI , name book you are drawing from = Signoff Sheet_May_01 ...(02)...(03)